# awk + add print in case of match

Tags: awk

I write the following awk (  print VAL_1 & VAL_2 if match in file )

```
   awk -v VAL_1=$NET -v VAL_2=$NET_SPEED   '$1 == VAL_1 && $2 == VAL_2 '  file
```

how to add in awk the print command ,

in order to print the word MATCH

```
 if 

    $1=VAL_1 
 & 
    $2=VAL_2
```

lidia

Comment: You should always quote your shell variables, unless you specifically need a reason not to: `awk -v VAL_1="$NET" -v VAL2="$NET_SPEED" ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$1 == VAL_1 && $2 == VAL_2 { print "MATCH" }
```